# Print two different maps object in one layout template in Arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, java, printing

I'm trying to publish a print service that accepts two maps objects, sent by javascript and print them, I found PrintTask() wedjit, something like printTask.map=map, my goal is to try to send two map, somthing like

```
          printTask.map1=map1;
          printTask.map2=map2;
```

And the result to be as in the picture
[image]

Is it possible to do that?! and How to achieve this?